# Semantically marking up branding (sitename and logo)

Tags: html

What's the ideal way to semantically mark-up branding on a web page? When I was using HTML 4 in 2011 I would do one of the following (depending if an logo was required)

```
<div id="top">
    <a href="/">
        <p id="branding">JJ Media Limited</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="top">
    <a href="/">
        <p id="branding"><img id="logo" src="images/logo.png"/> JJ Media Limited</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

I was against wrapping the branding in a header, or added the logo as a background with CSS because I feel the logo is contextual.

But, with HTML5 has anything changed in the way you semantically markup branding? Are there any logical changes to convention?

P.S I know the id tag 'top' is ambiguous, I was using it purely for demonstration purposes.

Comment: I think best practice is to put it in a `<header>`.

Comment: @DanielImms To use the header element would require the use of a H1. Although I see some sites doing (and a number that don't) I think it's semantically wrong - a company's name and/or logo isn't really the head of a section in the document.

Comment: This information (company name/app name) would normally be put in the `<title>` as well. I think because it's captured in the `<title>` it doesn't matter so much in the content.

Comment: @JamesJeffery The header element explicitly does NOT require use of a h1 heading - "A header element is intended to usually contain the section's heading (an h1–h6 element), but this is not required. The header element can also be used to wrap a section's table of contents, a search form, or any relevant logos." See the specification at http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-header-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, but still pretty much the same..

```
<header>
    <a href="/"><img src="img.png" alt="image description"/></a>
</header>
```

Comment: Consider accessibility and search engines in your answer - you have no (required) alternate text for the image nor any non-visual content.